# Wrong application icon shown in app Settings info and while installation

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have used the https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons to generate my app icons. My pubspec.yaml is like this,

```
dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.0

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icons/appIcon.png"
```

And my AndroidManifest.xml is

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.max.test_flutter_appppp">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="test_flutter_appppp"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The app launcher icon is updated correctly **but at certain places, the default flutter icon is shown**.
Please see the screenshots below ,

[image]

[image]

The App icon is correctly shown in home screen but inside Settings/RecentApps and during installation, the default flutter icon is shown.

My Phone is Poco f1 and its running Android 10.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have run your app in release mode.

if not then please uninstall your app and try it in release mode using `flutter run --release` command or profile mode using `flutter run --profile` command.

Then it should work.

Comment: I am trying in Release mode only. Its still not working.

Comment: I also tried it. It seems the issue happens only in my Poco f1 phone. The same app works well on my Samsung s4 tab.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying this website out to convert your images to App icons. In my personal experience, it has been great and seems to be the easiest way to change your app icon. Just go to this link https://appicon.co/ and upload your image. Select the devices you want to generate the icons for and download the archive.

#### Android

Then just go and copy all the folders (the mipmap stuff) in the `android` folder from the downloaded archive in `your project\android\app\src\main\res\`

#### iOS

Then just go and copy the `Assets.xcassets` from the downloaded archive in `your project\ios\Runner\` and override the existing one there.

P.S. The converter also generates icons for Play Store and App Store.

Comment: I did these steps but the icons are still the default flutter image.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the files right? maybe try running ```flutter clean``` in the terminal, uninstall the app from the device and run a clean install again.

Comment: I also tried it. It seems the issue happens only in my Poco f1 phone. The same app works well on my Samsung s4 tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this,

```
dependencies:
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.0

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icons/appIcon.png"
```